# How to join Windows AD domain without configuring DNS servers for clients?

Tags: networking, dns, active-directory

I have to manually set DNS servers for clients so they can communicate with AD controller. If I want to use a laptop in other networks and have to configure Windows to use DHCP. I would like to use DHCP and still be able to communicate with AD controller. Which DNS servers are provided by DHCP cannot be configured.

Comment: Why you have to manually set them ? DHCP is not set inside your clients network ?

Comment: Does your AD use a global domain, or a made-up domain (like something.lan or something.corp)?

Comment: @yagmoth555 DHCP is configured outside our clients network.

Comment: @grawity global

Comment: @JPX Then I'm not sure what problems you're having? A global domain should be resolveable using any servers. Unless your DCs block DNS in their firewall?

Comment: @gravity Resolvable domain name is not enough for domain controller. You need to configure SRV records in DNS servers. We have those records in our own DNS server/domain controller. Problem is that DHCP will not give our DNS servers for clients.

Comment: @JPX: SRV records are resolved the same way as anything else about the domain name is resolved. They're not special in any way; they don't have to be "direct". I still fail to see the problem.

Comment: @grawity There's no SRV records in DNS servers which are given by DHCP. There's no way to change any configuration how DHCP or external DNS servers work.

Comment: @JPX: But you said you use a global domain for AD. That means those records don't have to be on DNS servers given by DHCP – they only have to be _on your domain's DNS servers_. For example, `ad.ucsd.edu` is a global DNS domain that runs AD and that allows `_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.ad.ucsd.edu` SRV to be resolved from anywhere, using any DNS servers.

Comment: @grawity Sorry. For example ad.example.com is global and DNS servers given by DHCP will resolve IP address but those DNS servers won't relay queries to ad.example.com. Client01.example.com will get DNS servers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy from DHCP server but clien01 cannot join domain ad.example.com unless you manually configure the IP address of ad.example.com as a DNS server for client 01.

Comment: @JPX: They **can** and they will relay those queries. If they won't relay queries then that's only because the parent domain (example.com) lacks NS records pointing to the child domain. There's no other reason why they wouldn't – it's how all domains are glued together. The domain I gave earlier as an example, and the domain we use at work, both have proper NS records and so all queries _are_ relayed by any DHCP-issued DNS server in the world.

Comment: @grawity DNS servers won't relay queries. I checked that. That's the problem. All servers and devices are like device01.example.com. DNS dns1.example.com won't relay queries to our-ad-and-dns.example.com. That's why I'm looking a way to configure clients to connect to our-ad-and-dns.example.com without DNS server.

Comment: Is that because you ended up having two DNS zones identically named? (I.e. both AD and non-AD called "example.com"?)

Comment: It's because the network is not our but we need to work on it. All we get are static IP adresses for eg  our-ad-and-dns.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

In order to participate in a Windows Active Directory domain, your computer must be able to resolve DNS queries made against said domain's DNS namespace. No ifs, ands or buts about it.

It doesn't matter *which* DNS servers you use to resolve the queries, as long as they provide accurate and up-to-date answers to the client's questions. In a recommended configuration, these are Active Directory-integrated DNS servers. However, using third-party DNS servers is supported, but that requires a lot more configuration and administrative overhead.

You can provide the required DNS lookup capability to your computer one of two ways:

1. Configure your device to use DNS servers that are valid for the domain. This can be done via either DHCP or static IP configuration settings.
2. Configure the DNS server(s) your computer is using to either host the active directory domain's DNS namespace, or forward queries targeting the domain to DNS servers authoritative for the domain.

The third option, making your domain resolvable over the public Internet is also an option, but not recommended because of the privacy implications.